# making a better search without lagging

Tags: java, android, search

So i have this edditbox that search the data.txt for stopname and display it to the listview using my custom adapter, so every time I input a word it filters for results.

**My problem is that it lags a little bit as I input a word again cause I think is filters all the result.**

My question is how can I make it not lag I know my is there a way to do the filtering of data in the background?

PS. my data.txt is a very big collection of data lets say 100mb of stop name data

```
searchEditText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

                customAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you first display some certain words, and then may be on scroll display next search results or even on a load more button click display more records. It is not presumably correct to display such a huge data all at once. Considering different android devices, and the processor speed , some devices may not respond at all.

Answer (score 1):

since you need to search in a huge file, and putting it all into the heap memory is too dangerous (can get OOM) , you can do the next things to make things a bit better:

1. load the file into the JNI code and do the search there. sure it will take some loading time and take memory and will make the OS prefer to kill your process when it goes to the background, but it will be much faster.
2. cache previous results
3. compress the file so that more work would be on the CPU instead of the storage unit.
4. think of a better way to help the searching, based on the data and the queries. since i don't have any idea of either the data or the queries, i can't be more specific. for example, if all of the text is in english, you could use ascii instead of unicode, so each character would take a single byte instead of 2 bytes.
5. if it's so slow, you could even put it on a remote server and query it from the device. there you could load it all into memory and always be ready for queries.
6. you could use some kind of [**search algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) to be done on your data to make it faster to search. I think the KMP algorithm seems ok . there is a nice implementation of it [**here**](http://tekmarathon.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/algorithm-to-find-substring-in-a-string-kmp-algorithm/), i think (didn't test it). there is a video describing how it works [**here**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFof0Mx_-Ac) . maybe you don't have to do it since the built in implementation of how to search for strings is already quite efficient, so do it only if you've tried the other solutions.

   also, i think regular expression can achieve the same thing.

no matter which of those you choose, remember that it's still a low-spec device compared to a full blown PC, so be careful with RAM usage or you will get OOM on some devices.